# Loopback4 and MongoDB query documents with null or undefined field

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

How do I query for document with fields that are null or undefined?

e.g.

```
{id:1, updatedAt: null}
{id:2}
```

I already tried this code to no avail. Returns 0 matches.

```js
const whereBuilder = new WhereBuilder();
const where: Where = whereBuilder
  .eq('updatedAt', null)
//.eq('updatedAt', false)
  .build();

myRepository.findOne({
  where: where,
});
```

Thanks for the Help!

Edit 1: Field declaration on model.

```
@property({
  type: 'date',
})
updatedAt?: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### In MongoDB Shell

using [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types) operator to match `undefined` value, see [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/).

```js
// match `undefined`
db.TEST.findOne({ updatedAt: {'$type':6}  });
// match `null`
db.TEST.findOne({ updatedAt: null  });
```

#### In LB4

```js
// match `undefined`
return await this.myRepository.find(
    {
        where: {
            // !!!! "$" will be added automatically here. (explained below)
            updatedAt: { 'type': 6 }
        },
    }
);
// match `null`
return await this.myRepository.find(
    {
        where: {
            updatedAt: null
        },
    }
);
```

#### Why `{ 'type': 6 }` will be converted into `{ '$type': 6 }` ?

`./node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js` line 918:

your `where` will be refactored in this function

```js
MongoDB.prototype.buildWhere = function(modelName, where, options) {
    ...
```

and in line 1011, `{ 'type': 6 }` will be converted into `{ '$type': 6 }`

```js
   ...
      } else {
        query[k] = {};
        query[k]['$' + spec] = cond;
      }
   ...
```

by the way, in line 1016, you can see `null` will converted as `{$type: 10}`

```js
   ...
      if (cond === null) {
        // http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/
        // Null: 10
        query[k] = {$type: 10};
      } else {
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 

Would not work as the field is declared as:

`@property({
    type: 'date',
  })
  updatedAt?: string;`

I'm getting a type error when I use the code above.

Comment: `{ where: { updatedAt:  <Where<AnyObject>>{ 'type': 6 }  }}` or `{ where: { updatedAt: { 'type': 6 } as AnyObject  }}`